# Can Some Help me to fix html link

Tags: html, css, blogger

hey I need help with this code I want the link to open in a new tab instead
i want the link to be opened in new tab instead of the current one

```
    <form>
<input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Your Text Here" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.yourdomain.com'" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a form rather than a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) or an [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)? You could likely use an a element with a target of _blank instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Javascript use: [WINDOW.OPEN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```
<form>
<input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Your Text Here" onclick="window.open('http://www.yourdomain.com')" />
</form>
```

Comment: wow thanks this one worked @MohcinBN

Comment: Good, enjoy, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In order to target new window you need to make use of `target="" property`
Also `window.location.href` contains link of current url.

```
<form>
<input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Your Text Here" onclick="window.location='http://www.yourdomain.com'" target="_blank"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The target property is for links: OP is using a form rather than a link so this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Hey to make the link open in new tab you have to add target= "_blank"

Like this

```
  <form>
<input class="MyButton" type="button" target="_blank" value="Your Text Here" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.yourdomain.com'" />
</form>
```

Comment: The target property is for links: OP is using a form rather than a link so this won't work

Comment: You are right bro. have overseen that